# How can I import the translation of the standard field?

Tags: translation, translation-workbench

I try to import the `XLF` file containing some standard fields, for instance `Account.BillingAddress`.

Here's how the field is defined:

```
<trans-unit id="CustomField.Account.BillingAddress.FieldLabel" maxwidth="40" size-unit="char">
  <source>Billing Address</source>
  <target>Faktureringsadresse</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Sadly, I receive the following error when uploading the file in the Translation Workbench:

> [File contains translation keys that don't match the translation type specified in the file header. Create separate import files for metadata and data translation.]

The hint from the [Common Errors with Exporting and Importing Translation Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=workbench_troubleshooting.htm&type=5&language=en_US) article is very general and I don't think that it relates to my problem:

> The file contains at least one key with a translation type that doesn’t match the file type in the header.

> Create separate import files for metadata and data translation.

I have the impression that translating standard fields is not supported via this method, as they are not retrieved via the "export" option as well. I tried to find some useful information about this problem in the [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench.htm&type=5) section of SF Docs, but with no success.

Has anyone occurred such a problem before? How can I import standard field translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the Translation Workbench,  only apply the changes for Custom Object or Custom fields and not Standard Objects or Standard Fields.

You have an option to rename the standard objects and fields. Please refer the below article [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315332&type=1)